# WordPress website doesn't load after installing theme

Tags: wordpress

I have installed: http://themeforest.net/item/123ecology-corporate-ecommerce-wordpress-theme/4561597 on my domain. It stops working as I activated it. Now an empty page is loading, either I try to load dashboard or front-end. I faced this problem earlier on another site. But on that it occurs for a few time.

My Current website is: http://primeimports.ca/

Comment: what version of WP are you using??

Comment: First issue you should look at

The character encoding of the HTML document was not declared. The document will render with garbled text in some browser configurations if the document contains characters from outside the US-ASCII range. The character encoding of the page must be declared in the document or in the transfer protocol.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This usually happens when their is a PHP error in the theme's code.  If you have access to the files via FTP perhaps, just delete the theme folder and your Wordpress installation will work again.

Comment: Thanks dcc & user3750649, I removed theme and existing installation works.